# NoMethodError (undefined method `encode' for JsonWebToken:Module):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I am referring to [this blog](https://www.sitepoint.com/authenticate-your-rails-api-with-jwt-from-scratch) for token based authentication. I am trying to access the `jsonwebtoken.rb` methods as specified in the above blog in my `app/controllers/api/v1/registrations_controller.rb`.

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def create
      auth_token = JsonWebToken.encode({user_id: user.id})
    end
  end
end
```

My `jsonwebtoken.rb` file is inside `app/lib` folder as specified in the blog mentioned above. I have no idea how to use the methods of `jsonwebtoken.rb` in my different controllers.

Also I have added `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` to autoload the file in `config/application.rb`. Please help me. Somewhere, I am missing the concept.

Comment: use `include JsonWebToken` inside the controller where you want to use the methods of the lib file.

Comment: have you require 'json_web_token' this in controller?

Comment: after adding `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` just restart  yr server and then call anywhere in the app folder `JsonWebToken.encode({user_id: 1})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in the file naming convention see your file name is `jsonwebtoken.rb` but the class is `JsonWebToken` so the file name will `json_web_token.rb` look at the console

```
2.3.4 :019 > "JsonWebToken".underscore
 => "json_web_token"
```

Rails [**`UnderScore`**](https://apidock.com/rails/String/underscore) method.

Restart the server after made any changes.

Here is the very nice tutorial for [RESTful JSON API With Rails 5](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one), you can check this.